# How does a broadcast receiver work among activities?

Tags: android, android-broadcastreceiver, activity-stack

I have multiple activities suppose A , B , C , D and all are register to same BroadCastReceiver. While sending the broadcast message in which order activities will receive the broadcast intents. Is it in order like A , B , C , D or random.

Please let me know, give me some suggestions.

Comment: I've never done this, but just thinking out loud ... only 1 Activity is active at a time, so maybe the active one gets notified first?

Comment: did you read the doc? : https://developer.android.com/guide/components/broadcasts.html. especially played for sendOrderedBroadcast(Intent, String) . so i would say it depends. your question does not give the information needed to be clear about it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have no control of that, because System dispatches those actions to registered broadcast listeners. You have no any guarantee on the ordering broadcast listeners will be fired at.

Unless it is ordered broadcast. From [docs](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/broadcasts.html#sending_broadcasts):

> The **sendOrderedBroadcast(Intent, String)** method sends broadcasts to one receiver at a time. As each receiver executes in turn, it can propagate a result to the next receiver, or it can completely abort the broadcast so that it won't be passed to other receivers. The order receivers run in can be controlled with the **android:priority** attribute of the matching intent-filter; receivers with the same priority will be run in an arbitrary order.

Comment: Oh! , thanks man , i got my doubt cleared.  Yes it will be pretty random. I was thinking may be Activity Stack will play the role, which Activity is on top that will receive first.

Comment: as my comment says: its not clear, ordered broadcasts are there

Comment: @HenningLuther, good point. I automatically assumed ordinary broadcasts. Will edit my answer. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

There are possibilities to have ordered broadcasts. It depends if you are the one broadcasting. If you are broadcasting use `sendOrderedBroadcast(Intent, String)` and give priority to your receivers. If someone else is the broadcaster you have to know if he is sending ordered or not. If he doesnt, you have no chance, otherwise you can priotize your receivers.

Answer (score 1):

There are three way to send `Broadcast` in android. Namely 1. `sendBroadcast` 2. `sendOrderedBroadcast`, and 3. `sendStickyBroadcast`. Here you are talking about `sendBroadcast` so it will simply dispatch the broadcast to registered broadcast receiver regardless in which order broadcast has been registered.